# Get file that PrintWriter writes to

Tags: java, file, printwriter

How do you get the name of the file that a PrintWriter object is writing to?

```
PrintWriter myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
```

I need the fileName parameter.

Comment: What if it's not writing to a file? `new PrintWriter(System.out)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't - it might not even be writing to a file, e.g.

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrinterWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
```

If you need this information, you could potentially create a subclass of `PrintWriter` which remembers (and exposes) the file it's writing to... but usually the need to do this indicates that you're best off taking a look at your design and reconsidering it. (Personally I tend to avoid `PrintWriter` anyway, as I don't like exceptions just being swallowed, but that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 0):

If you write to file, your can use this code:

```
File f = new File("some_file.txt");
f.createNewFile();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f));
```

Or you can use name of the file:

```
PrintWriter myPrintWriter = new PrintWriter("some_file.txt", "UTF-8");
```

If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size; otherwise, a new file will be created.